# Removing elements from one to/until another

Tags: javascript

Let's have an example:

```
<table>
    <tr class="need"></tr>
    <tr class="no-need"></tr> // This is ourElement, needs to be removed
    <tr></tr>                 // This element needs to be removed
    <tr class="no-need"></tr> // This element needs to be removed
    <tr class="no-need"></tr> // This element needs to be removed
    <tr class="need"></tr>    // Elements removed until this
</table>
```

I want to remove those four elements at once.

This is what I've done:

```
function remove(ourElement) {
    var body = ourElement.parentNode,
        bodyRows = body.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < bodyRows.length; i++) {
        if (bodyRows[i] == ourElement) {
            if (!bodyRows[i+1].className) {
                body.removeChild(bodyRows[i+1]);
            }
        }
        if (bodyRows[i] > ourElement) {
            if (bodyRows[i].className == 'no-need') {
                body.removeChild(bodyRows[i]);
            }
            if (bodyRows[i].className == 'need') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    body.removeChild(ourElement);
}
```

The function removes only the first empy row after `ourElement` and the `ourElement` itself.

As i wrote above, I need to remove those four elements at first run of our function.

Pure Javascript needed.

Comment: Why not `if (!bodyRows[i+1].className || bodyRows[i+1].className ==  'no-need'){`

Comment: Remove the `if (bodyRows[i].className == 'need'){ break; }`

Comment: @JCOC611 I need to break out of the loop when the first `need` element after `ourElement` is achieved, to not remove all what's below of this element.

Comment: `if (bodyRows[i] > ourElement)` is nonsense, DOM elements can't be compared to each other, what would be the result in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
function remove(ourElement) {
    var body = ourElement.parentNode;
    var childRows = body.childNodes;

    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < childRows.length; i++) {
        var row = childRows[i];

        if(found) {
            if(!row.className || row.className == "no-need") {
                body.removeChild(row);
                i--; // as the number of element is changed
            } else if(row.className == "need") {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(row == ourElement) {
            body.removeChild(ourElement);
            found = true;
            i--; // as the number of element is changed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just realised you may be looking for a function to delete items inside boundaries lets say:
items between class"need" and class"need" and delete all items inside them. if thats your question the answer is as follows:

```
function remove( tagElement, boundClass ) {

    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName(tagElement), 
        re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+ boundClass +"(\\s|$)"),
        bound = false,
        r = [];

    for( var i=0, len=tr.length; i<len; i++ )  {

        if(  re.test(tr[i].className) ) { 
            bound = ( bound === true ) ? false : true;            
            if(bound) continue;
        }

        if( bound ) r.push( tr[i] );
    }

    while( r.length )
        r[ r.length - 1 ].parentNode.removeChild( r.pop() ); 

}

remove( "tr", "need" ); // use it like this
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `<` or `>` operators with DOM elements.

```
function remove(ourElement) {
    var body = ourElement.parentNode,
        bodyRows = body.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        lb = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < bodyRows.length; i++) {
        lb = (lb)?(bodyRows[i] == ourElement):lb;
        if(lb){
          if (!bodyRows[i].className) {
              body.removeChild(bodyRows[i]);
          }else if (bodyRows[i].className == 'no-need') {
              body.removeChild(bodyRows[i]);
          }else if (bodyRows[i].className == 'need') {
              break;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to decrease index `i` every time when removing child, as the number is changed and elements are being shifted

Comment: Keen observation! I completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

Try this, every time it removes a child it decreases i to compensate:

```
function remove(ourElement) {
    var body = ourElement.parentNode,
        bodyRows = body.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        lb = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < bodyRows.length; i++) {
        if (!lb && bodyRows[i] != ourElement) {
            continue;
        } else if(bodyRows[i] == ourElement){
            lb = true;
        }
            if (bodyRows[i].className == 'no-need' || !bodyRows[i].className) {
                body.removeChild(bodyRows[i]);
                i--;
            }
    }
}
```